# Android app failing when trying to log in with GitHub with Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I tried to make a login page with GitHub using Firebase and it fails every time and I don't know why. There are no failing logs or errors and the big problem is that it worked and now it doesn't and I didn't change anything. This is the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/github-auth

- I put my SH1 in Firebase, I enabled the provider, I put the secret and the id in the Firebase provider
- The same thing happens when I try with Twitter, I think the provider doesn't work somehow

This is the code:

```
public void onClickGitHubButtonLogIn(String name) {
    provider = OAuthProvider.newBuilder("github.com");
    // Target specific email with login hint.
    provider.addCustomParameter("login", name);
    // Request read access to a user's email addresses.

    List<String> scopes =
            new ArrayList<String>() {
                {
                    add("user:email");
                }
            };
    provider.setScopes(scopes);

    Task<AuthResult> pendingResultTask = mAuth.getPendingAuthResult();
    if (pendingResultTask != null) {

        // There's something already here! Finish the sign-in for your user.
        pendingResultTask
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                openMainPageActivity();
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            }
                        });
    } else {
        Log.i("TAG","Enters here");
        mAuth
                .startActivityForSignInWithProvider(/* activity= */ this, provider.build())
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                FirebaseUser firebaseUser=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                                Log.i("TAG","a intrat aici3");
                                openMainPageActivity();
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Log.i("TAG","Enters here");
                            }
                        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is onSuccess or onFailure  even triggered?

Comment: The second onFailure is triggered on the "else" branch

Comment: What's the exact error message that you get?

Comment: There is no error it just fails, github developer makes an account. Firebase is the problem